# nftables remove all rules in chain

Tags: nftables

I have a number of rules in table `mytable` chain `mychain`:

```bsh
> sudo nft -a list table mytable
table ip mytable { # handle 8
        chain mychain { # handle 1
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                tcp dport 5550 accept # handle 18
                tcp dport 5551 accept # handle 19
                tcp dport 5552 accept # handle 20
                tcp dport 5553 accept # handle 21
                tcp dport 5554 accept # handle 22
        }
}
```

According to [nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Simple_rule_management#Removing_all_the_rules_in_a_chain) it should be possible to remove all rules from the specified chain.
However the following command returns error:

```bsh
> sudo nft delete rule mytable mychain
Error: syntax error, unexpected newline, expecting handle
delete rule mytable mychain
                           ^
```

What is the proper command to remove all rules from `mychain` without iterating over rule handles?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are still some errors lurking in the nftables wiki. The actual syntax is quite logical:

- to remove everything

  ```
  nft flush ruleset
  ```
- to empty a table (with `ip` as family by default if not specified). Eg for `my table`

  ```
  nft flush table mytable
  ```
- to delete a table (which also empties it first). Eg for `mytable`

  ```
  nft delete table mytable
  ```
- **to empty a chain** (ditto). Eg for `mytable mychain`

  ```
  nft flush chain mytable mychain
  ```
- to delete a chain (ditto). Eg for `mytable mychain`

  ```
  nft delete chain mytable mychain
  ```
- to delete a rule (this can still be done only by the handle reference). Eg for `tcp dport 5550 accept # handle 18`

  ```
  nft delete rule mytable mychain handle 18
  ```

The thing to remember is what the action is done unto. If you want to do an operation at the *chain* level, then it's normal there's the `chain` keyword.

In case of doubt, the [`nft` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8) is usually more accurate, but of course one has to know in advance the information is in the [CHAINS](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#CHAINS) section rather than the [RULES](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#RULES) section:

> **CHAINS**
>
> {add | create} chain [family] table chain [ { type type hook hook [device device] priority priority ; [policy policy ;] } ]
>   {delete | list | **flush**} **chain** [family] **table** **chain**
>   delete chain [family] table handle handle
>   rename chain [family] table chain newname
>
> [...]
>   **flush** Flush all rules of the specified chain.

Comment: It seems not possible to remove more than one handle with one command, even if the rules are part of the same chain

Comment: @Polizi8 you can remove *all* of the chain's rules in one command, as was OP's question about (and as described in bold in my answer).

Comment: @Polizi8 also (I forgot it), nftables can do transactions: you can remove two rules in the same transaction, turning a chain with 5 rules to a chain with 3 rules, never going through the state with 4 rules, in a single transaction. With the `-f` option of the `nft` command.

Comment: These commands do not work on the version I am running  (v0.9.3). I must include the family in the commands. Example: `nft flush chain filter output` fails. But `nft flush chain inet filter output` works.

Comment: @Dave that's because the default table family is `ip` which can be omitted, not `inet` which (represents `ip`+`ip6` and) has to be stated. You have to read between the lines, examples don't always apply. But they did apply to OP's question.